Delete Pod without restarting other resources/object
I currently have this bash script that do cleanup obsolete resources for deployment, services, and configmaps. when I try to add the kubectl delete pod on the script, then it will delete all the remaining pods, but the problem is for a certain scenario wherein I will cleanup only the pods that do not have or without the object like the deployment, services, and configmaps it will also restart the pods due to the kubectl delete pod and I do not want the other pods or resources also to restart but only delete the specific pod that have only an object pod, then for the other pod that have the object of deployment, services, and configmaps should not be restarted.
Here's the script:
      active_pods=$(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}')
      active_deployments=$(kubectl get deployments -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}')
      active_services=$(kubectl get services -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}')
      active_configmaps=$(kubectl get configmap -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}')

      readarray -t active_pods_array <<<"$active_pods"
      readarray -t active_deployments_array <<<"$active_deployments"
      readarray -t active_services_array <<<"$active_services"
      readarray -t active_configmaps_array <<<"$active_configmaps"

      echo "active pods: ${active_pods_array[@]}"
      for pod in "${active_pods_array[@]}"; do
        if ! grep -q "pod/${pod} " nonprod.txt && [[ -n $pod ]] ; then
          kubectl delete pod "$pod"
        fi
      done

      echo "active deployments: ${active_deployments_array[@]}"
      for deployment in "${active_deployments_array[@]}"; do
        if ! grep -q "deployment.apps/${deployment} " nonprod.txt && [[ -n $deployment ]] ; then
          kubectl delete deployment "$deployment"
        fi
      done

      echo "active services: ${active_services_array[@]}"
      for service in "${active_services_array[@]}"; do
        if ! grep -q "service/${service} " nonprod.txt && [[ -n $service ]] && [[ $service != 'kubernetes' ]] ; then
          kubectl delete service "$service"
        fi
      done

      echo "active configmap: ${active_configmaps_array[@]}"
      for configmap in "${active_configmaps_array[@]}"; do
        if ! grep -q "configmap/${configmap} " nonprod.txt && [[ -n $configmap ]] && [[ ${configmap} != "kube-root-ca.crt" ]] ; then
          kubectl delete configmap "${configmap}"
        fi
      done


~ $ kubectl get pods
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
logging-event-7a8gl478e4-7pms9              1/1     Running   0             22m
my-workspace-92757a9w8p-ghedk               1/1     Running   0             25m
my-web-page-347817pt37-7wu1a                1/1     Running   0             21m
hello-world-8i64337229-4yd37                1/1     Running   0             21m
http-client-test                            1/1     Running   0             21m
mysql8demo-7425681afg-krdlh                 1/1     Running   0             22m
postgres16demo-4p25jr3g9k-2piex             1/1     Running   0             21m
mytestcurl                                  1/1     Running   0             21m
mytestdemo-9449873a4c-at5kg                 1/1     Running   0             22m

~ $ kubectl get deployment
NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
logging-event              1/1     1            1           22m
my-workspace               1/1     1            1           25m
my-web-page                1/1     1            1           21m
hello-world                1/1     1            1           21m
mysql8demo                 1/1     1            1           22m
postgres16demo             1/1     1            1           21m
mytestdemo                 1/1     1            1           22m

~ $ kubectl get service
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
logging-event              ClusterIP   ##########     <none>        8080/TCP   22m
my-web-page                ClusterIP   ##########     <none>        80/TCP     21m
hello-world                ClusterIP   ##########     <none>        80/TCP     21m
kubernetes                 ClusterIP   ##########     <none>        443/TCP    31m
mysql8demo                 ClusterIP   ##########     <none>        1433/TCP   22m
postgres16demo             ClusterIP   ##########     <none>        5432/TCP   21m
mytestdemo                 ClusterIP   ##########     <none>        8080/TCP   22m

~ $ kubectl get configmap
NAME                                                         DATA   AGE
logging-event                                                1      22m
my-workspace-scripts                                         1      26m
hello-world-html                                             1      21m
kube-root-ca.crt                                             1      31m
mysql8demo-hook                                              1      22m
mysql8demo-part-66772g4g2ba1fdd37d7273f2gs64b4a8-aa-cm       1      22m
postgres16demo-hook                                          1      22m
postgres16demo-part-9r54446g81dbr16836g4214g85189139-aa-cm   1      22m
mytestdemo-mappings                                          3      22m


Check this project kui

If you're just trying to clean things up, you might delete Deployments, Jobs, CronJobs, StatefulSets, and DaemonSets first.  It should be unusual to have unmanaged Pod, but those other objects will delete the Pods they own.  If you're trying to clean up everything just deleting the entire Namespace could also be a useful option.

it's not just cleaning things, I'm doing an automation here.

Found a way to filter out the "null" which is needed to be deleted exclusive only for the Pod that have "owner_kind" using the commands below.
Fix on my script:
active_pods=$(kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items[] | select( .metadata.ownerReferences[0].kind == null )' | jq '.metadata.name' --raw-output)

Test from my terminal:
~ $ kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items[] | select( .metadata.ownerReferences[0].kind == null )' | jq '.metadata.name' --raw-output
http-client-test
mytestcurl

List that show "Replicaset" and "Null":
~ $ kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items[] | {name: (.metadata.name), owner_kind: .metadata.ownerReferences[0].kind,}'
{
  "name": "logging-event-7a8gl478e4-7pms9",
  "owner_kind": "ReplicaSet"
}
{
  "name": "my-workspace-92757a9w8p-ghedk",
  "owner_kind": "ReplicaSet"
}
{
  "name": "my-web-page-347817pt37-7wu1a",
  "owner_kind": "ReplicaSet"
}
{
  "name": "hello-world-8i64337229-4yd37",
  "owner_kind": "ReplicaSet"
}
{
  "name": "http-client-test",
  "owner_kind": null
}
{
  "name": "mysql8demo-7425681afg-krdlh",
  "owner_kind": "StatefulSet"
}
{
  "name": "postgres16demo-4p25jr3g9k-2piex",
  "owner_kind": "StatefulSet"
}
{
  "name": "mytestcurl",
  "owner_kind": null
}
{
  "name": "mytestdemo-9449873a4c-at5kg",
  "owner_kind": "ReplicaSet"
}


Try to use kubectl get pod -o json and then with jq filter you can filter the kind of the owner. The response from kubectl get pod -o json will be like,
{
"metadata": {
        "ownerReferences": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
                "blockOwnerDeletion": true,
                "controller": true,
                "kind": "StatefulSet",
                "name": "",
                "uid": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}

with JQ,
kubectl get pod <podname> -o json | jq '.metadata.ownerReferences[]?.kind'
This will give us the kind whether it's up by deployment or statefulset or pod, we can check this kind in if block before deleting the pod to ensure as,
echo "active pods: ${active_pods_array[@]}"
      for pod in "${active_pods_array[@]}"; do
        
        if [[! kubectl get pod "$pod" -o json | jq '.metadata.ownerReferences[]?.kind' =~ ^("Statefulset"|"Deployment")$ ]]; 
        then
          kubectl delete pod "$pod"
        fi
      done

This is just idea, I'm not sure about the scripting.
